# How can I get response(which is searched by score) in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
I need your help. I want to a search which can be search by common conditions and its score range also used as conditions。Can I do it successfully? if you know ,I hope you can share.


I have a example in the picture:
```

[In the picture,we know the score range is [0,1] ,if I want to get response which scores is [0.2,0.6],How do it! help! SOS! Execute my English!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8RSh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch provides a [`min_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html) field that can be included in a request body search to filter out documents with a `_score` less than a specified value.

There is no way to filter out documents with a `_score` greater than a certain value, but: why do you want to do this?  Scores in Lucene by definition mean that documents were found matching your search query, and that some results are more relevant than others.  I recommend that you read ["What is Relevance?"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/relevance-intro.html) in the Elasticsearch documentation, and ["Apache Lucene - Scoring"](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/scoring.html) for a basic understanding of how the scoring formula works.

Also, the Lucene score range isn't *always* `[0,1]`: it can be greater than `1`.

Comment: Yes ,you are right,I has tried. But ,"max_score"  is not a param. Thank you!

Comment: You're right it's not because such a feature doesn't make practical sense.